# BigQuery - Ingest integer as timestamp into table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that had a column in its schema defined as `TIMESTAMP`.

I tried loading data into this table using a load job and the data for that column was integers (seconds since 1970-01-01), but it didnt ingest it properly, I see that all the dates are very close to 1970-01-01 (slightly later than midnight on that day).

Is it possible to ingest integers as `TIMESTAMP`? If so, what do I need to change? The file is an AVRO file.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using AVRO's logical types and the `useAvroLogicalTypes` property that you can specify in BQ's load job config.